The package system is broken Depends: libjpeg62-turbo-dev (>= 1:2.0.6-4)
I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and facing an issue I can't resolve. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix it?
Ubuntu Release:

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
Description:  Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:  24.04
Codename: noble

The error I'm encountering is:
Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
Transaction failed: The package system is broken
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libjpeg-dev: Depends: libjpeg62-turbo-dev (>= 1:2.0.6-4) but it is not installed

As deb packages are specific to a release; we can't provide much help given you've not told us what release you're using. A quick scan for that package and I don't see it available for any supported release of Ubuntu; so either you're using an unsupported release, OR its a third party package.  online search details can be see https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libjpeg62&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all but I searched using command line

Thanks for the comment, I have updated the description with the release details.

Please edit your question and give the exact command you ran and the complete output produced. Not just the error message. Please also format it properly.

How about sudo apt remove libjpeg-dev?

@OrganicMarble I was trying to check the updates for the system and getting the error message I shared above.

The solution is to remove the problematic package with
sudo apt remove libjpeg-dev

You can reinstall it after the upgrade
